# Binding ui components to observables in magento 2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, knockoutjs

I'm developing a custom step in magento2 checkout. I'm adding new fields dynamically by injecting appropriate XML in a plugin. New fields are ui components, children of a group (called additionalInformations) that is a child of new step view (uiComponent view). I would like to extend quote with an extra variable like additionalInformations and bind my group to that variable so the data could be accessible everywhere from quote singleton. Extending is quite simple using underscore:

```
_.extend(quote, {additionalInformations: ko.observable(null)});
```

My question is how can I bind my additionalInformations group in view to quote.additionalInformations observable?

I am an expert neither of Magento 2 nor knockout so please, guide me to do it in a better way if it is possible.